# Black screen after updating Google Play Services:7.5.0

Tags: android, google-play, android-5.0-lollipop

I updated my Google Play Service to be able to use Android 5.0 Material Design Support Library.

Since I did it, it happens quite often that my app end in ANR with  a black screen , and Nothing in logs.
So basically, it becomes very hard to debug, when I don't have logs to help me!
I've checked /data/anr/traces.txt but there is not much and process to extract it is not so fast...

Is there a solution to that or should I revert Google Play Service to his old version and wait more stable release???

PS: I upgraded Google Play Service through SDK Manager.
Is there a way to revert Google Play Service to the old version???

EDIT: It might be a solution to manage Android SDK in a Git Rep.
So revert changes would be no problem

Screenshot :

[image]

Comment: it is the one handled in official documentation: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 0):

double tap the home button.. that voice command will open.. press and say settings, and from the settings uninstall the updates of google play services..